# "Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type" TS

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I receive an error in Typescript code when I use my "language" const: "Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type."

```
const language =
      localStorage.getItem("language") !== null
        ? localStorage.getItem("language")
        : "en"; 
     
someText = someArray[language];
```

How can I fix it and why isn't working when I prevent language const from being null?
(I know that index selector must by string/number)

Comment: Probably a minor point but `someArray` is most likely not an array. It's some sort of object, likely `Record<string, string>` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here (and the reason why TypeScript cannot infer the correct type of `language`) is that `localStorage.getItem("language")` is being evaluated two times, and it could as well - for what the compiler knows - return `null` upon the second invocation.

Use the `??` operator to exclude the possibility of `language` being `null`.

```
const language = localStorage.getItem("language") ?? "en"; 
someText = someArray[language];
```

Comment: When I use your solution I get new error message: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ key: string; cz: string; en: string; }'"

Comment: In that case, you probably need to cast the result ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzg9gtiAggJ2QQwJ4C4IG8IDWI20YyAlgHYDmA3BAMYBeOUZVdEIlr7N9AXwgBePIWI4A5EQySANIxYRJzeVx7LukiANoBYAFChIsBABUQADzA40lDPoOGGMSmwjA71AK5pqIEQgACmAYBjRgAGUwGHR-ADp-MABJMBA4IIAiTxpff0yASggAfmKITO5CiDQocQwYADMIMAwABxBG6HgkVEx6Q1MQC2tAwZR0DABtHJ8-EABdWiA)). If that still doesn't work, you'll need to show your complete code.

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BUooHZqozAAKAlmMHGQLZhLA3B4ybmU75oBm0NcAbwCwAKDhwYuAryg0AFADcUSAK7AAXHDSSyeAOYBKTdqi69g0ePEIIBeKn0qUeqgF44cpBATKAyjGhnYAA6FxgASWJ5ACIHPScXaIM4AH4UuGiEAC8kuHQ4AGtgAE8IbgliyjKJKUIUYjQAblFLKxs7Gq4iYDRNYTErcSLi4x19ZoHB7NHTcdbB5hmzCcGAXwBtAF04d3X5q37BweHNaLQIJgB9YYBGaIAafams04BhLLvHyaPFjIBRPCfJ5wVZfI4Wb7HEqnc5XYYAJgewOsLwy70RYPBcF+0QBGOBoOBhyxJwysOA1xKAGYkZC2qjou8aZjwTiAcyCSy4JsJvsWt8GPAoMAYCooHhOARujsMtFed9JF16j1gjI-igEAALORyMhRZKuAB8EPBZHKuqi62iw2i21c9rgSlUwGSxPBwtF4sldWIMr1jHWcQSwB5BP2qwM8sGHrFeDgMa9tW6KxBolWQA)

Comment: Please, try with `(localStorage.getItem("language") ?? "cz") as keyof typeof translates[number]`.

Comment: Thank you it's working finally.  Can I ask you, why is this working?

Comment: `typeof translates[number]` is the type of the elements of the `translates` array, which is defined as `{ key: string; cz: string; en: string; }`. The `keyof` operator results in the union type of the keys, i.e. `"key" | "cz" | "en"`. That is, the allowed keys for each `item` of `translates`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just tweak your code a bit using Nullish Coalescing operator (??), which is basically what is share by GOTO. Just explaining it's name & working.

```
let someText = someArray[(localStorage.getItem("language") ?? "en")]
```

From **MDN** docs,
The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.